# How do I import the database from Replit with "Import" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replit, replit-database

Id like to use import to import the database. Is this possible?

`import Database from "@replit/database"`

This doesn't work

I tried that without "@" and with other variations, but with no success

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@replit/database doesn't seem to support ESM. Try using `const Client = require("@replit/database");` instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.